# how can i change footable header style?

Tags: jquery, html, css, footable

I'm using footable on a project. When footable generates responsive table it makes th and td s within the same tr. 
But i want it to seperate th and tds. 
Let me try to explain with pictures.
I want it like that.

[image]

But it generates like that:

[image]

Basicly i'd like to seperate th and tds with different tr tags.

Is that even possible? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible and a lot of ways to do it. I'd say quickest way is to bind to the "expand.ft.row" event:

```
FooTable.init("#element", {
    on: {
        "expand.ft.row": function (e, ft, row) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                var detailTRs = row.$el.find(".footable-details > tbody > tr").not(".processed")
                detailTRs.before(function() {
                    return $("<tr>").append($(this).children("th"))
                }).addClass("processed")
            }, 1000);
        },
        "collapse.ft.row": function (e, ft, row) {
            //remove the leftover tr elements we created.
            row.$el.find(".footable-details > tbody > tr").remove()
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot dude, i'll try it when i get back to home but seriously how did u find that question? :D its been more than a week and i was totally hopeless for the answer.

Comment: I've been using footable a bit lately and have started stalking footable questions.